# Replace multiple values based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace two values from two different columns with another two values from two different columns. Example:

I want to replace all values that are `null` in column `value` where the value in column `variable` is `name` and the `source` is `a`. Also, I want to keep the source of the replace value.

```
variable | value    | source
name       np.NaN     a
name       John       b
email      qq@g.com   a
....       ....      ....
```

Expected output:

```
variable | value    | source
name       John       b
name       John       b
email      qq@g.com   a
....       ....      ....
```

And then I will just drop the duplicates. I am trying to do this with np.where, but without success.
I don't know how to do the multiple conditions and multiple replacements..

```
df['name'] = np.where(df['variable'] == 'name' and df['source'] == 'a' and df['value'].isnull(), ...)
```

Maybe there is more elegant way to do this. Also, faster the performance the better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this is a solution :

```
df[(df['variable'] =!'name') | (~df['value'].isna()) | (df['source'] =! 'a')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Question: Are you using this as a condition in np.where function? Because it says unexpected syntax and I dont quite get it.

Comment: If I understood well, you want to drop rows that have name in variable, nan in value and a in source. It is what this code does

Comment: I want to replace the value based on this conditions in `values` column and to keep the source value - `b`. The null values should be replaced with the value from the row with source `b`

Comment: Sorry but I'm missing something. Maybe could you edit your post to have a dataframe easily reproducible for us (create it through pd.DataFrame(...), print it in your notebook and then paste the result here) and put your final expected output